# Spartacus: Remove trailing slash from multi site root

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I have Spartacus multi site configuration as below,

```
B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
      context: {
        countryLang: [
          'te-te',
          'ca-gn'
        ],
      }
```

When entering URL **https://localhost.com:4200/ca-gn**, it redirects to **https://localhost.com:4200/ca-gn/**.

Here trailing slash getting added automatically.

I have below requirement,

1. If I'm entering URL **https://localhost.com:4200/ca-gn** it should remain at same URL.
2. If I'm entering URL **https://localhost.com:4200/ca-gn/** it should redirects to **https://localhost.com:4200/ca-gn**.

It looks Spartacus default behavior.
Is there any possibilities to get this overwritten for my expected behavior?